# Find bounding box for contours

Tags: c#, emgucv

```
using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage()) //allocate storage for contour approximation
         for (Contour<Point> contours = grayImage.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_LIST, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
         {
             Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);
            canny.Draw(new Rectangle(currentContour.BoundingRectangle.X, currentContour.BoundingRectangle.Y, currentContour.BoundingRectangle.Width, currentContour.BoundingRectangle.Height), new Gray(1), 1);
             canny.Draw(contours, new Gray(), 2);
         }
```

this code giving me the bounding boxes but not up to mark,in some cases contours is out of box.
unable to share sample output image because it require 10 reputation
if anybody have solution to this please reply!
thankyou.

Comment: You can check the Rectangle bounds before drawing it, maybe skip it if the bounds are out of the image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Image<Gray, Byte> canny = new Image<Gray, byte>(grayImage.Size);
     using (MemStorage storage = new MemStorage())
     for (Contour<Point> contours =grayImage.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, storage); contours != null; contours = contours.HNext)
     {
         //Contour<Point> currentContour = contours.ApproxPoly(contours.Perimeter * 0.05, storage);
         CvInvoke.cvDrawContours(canny, contours, new MCvScalar(255), new MCvScalar(255), -1, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.LINE_TYPE.EIGHT_CONNECTED, new Point(0, 0));
     }
using (MemStorage store = new MemStorage())
         for (Contour<Point> contours1= grayImage.FindContours(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CHAIN_APPROX_METHOD.CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.RETR_TYPE.CV_RETR_TREE, store); contours1 != null; contours1 = contours1.HNext)
         {
             Rectangle r = CvInvoke.cvBoundingRect(contours1, 1);
             canny.Draw(r, new Gray(255), 1);
         }
```

this method is giving me perfect bounding box!!